# How are STL containers in C++ actually implemented..

Tags: c++, stl

I get asked about this a lot. I have read various sources including the book from Bjarne Stroustrup. It says that the standard does not mandate any implementation for the STL containers. But I am still not clear. If there is no mandate on the implementation, does it mean that when using a vector or a list in my code , it may use a different data structures at different times?? And if it is the case, how is it decided which data structure will be used at which time?? I mean should it not be fixed that all STL containers will use a specific DS everytime??

Comment: Interesting question, indeed. Why dont you make a research to be 100% sure? Just download different STL versions for different platforms and compare vector implementations.

Comment: I suppose a person crazy enough could write `std::vector` to change the backing data structure at runtime based on some arcane logic, but this would be really unusual.

Comment: It is different for each container. Different containers have different guarantees. The vector, for example, **must** be implemented as a contiguous array in memory. Mostly though the containers are specified in terms of how they behave wrt time complexity and interface.

Comment: @user4581301: Realistically though, a `std::deque` might adapt to the cache line length.

Comment: @Galik thank you for the information. My question is more specifically about standard containers in c++ STL that we use, I am confused because I read a recent implementation of a map as a list while all this while I knew that it was implemented as a RB tree. So the question is what exactly are the implementations underneath the standard containers?? Or if there is no concrete implementation, how do they make the choices for the DS to use when you we create these container instances in code?

Answer (score 10):

The standard doesn't specify what data structures should be used to implement STL containers but it does make complexity guarantees and sometimes other guarantees (like a `vector` using contiguous memory) that generally restrict the choice of data structures that could reasonably be used by a conforming implementation to a small number of choices.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So the exact data structure to be used among the choices is picked randomly everytime we use the STL? Say I use std::vector in two files on the same platform, and I have 3 data structures that confirm to my requirements, one out of those three is picked randomly?

Comment: @abhi: No, of course not. The implementation of your standard library containers is determined by its authors, at the time they author it. And they don't decide how to implement it randomly of course. They decide how to implement it according to what they think is generally best based on their experience as software developers.

Comment: @Benjamin which takes me back to my original question, how do I know what are the implementations for the current STL containers? I know I am beginning to sound a bit stupid here, but I definitely want to know what is underneath the current containers and why the authors chose to go with it.

Comment: @abhi — Re: “how do I know” — you don’t, and almost always you shouldn’t care. As long as the library implementation meets the specifications that are in the standard, and you code is written with those specifications in mind, the details of how the container is implemented don’t matter. Your code works.

Answer (score 6):

> it may use a different data structures at different times?

Yes, it may. But we need to clearly define a "different time". If you compile it for platform P with standard library implementation I, then it will use the same data structure for as long as this program is run. If you change P or I and recompile, then another data structure may be used. "Different times" are separated by builds.

> how is it decided which data structure will be used at which time?

The standard imposes asymptotic complexity requirements, so that's a big criteria right there. Beyond that, an implementer may choose between different data structures that meet those requirements. Since implementers are also aware of platforms, they may choose a data structure that behaves better on the particular platform you are building on.

> I mean should it not be fixed that all STL containers will use a specific DS everytime?

No. What if someone comes up with a really cool and efficient data structure tomorrow, one that can completely meet and exceed the requirements of some standard library container? If the data structure is set fixed in the specification, instead of the complexity, it would not be allowed to use this better implementation. Not until the C++ standard is perhaps updated, a process that can take years.

Software engineering is about balancing specification and abstraction. You must specify what is required to solve a problem, and abstract the details that are not relevant to the solution. If you over specify, you lose flexibility. But be careful not to over abstract and lose performance. The standard library is a great case study of an attempt to balance the two.

Comment: I can imagine the container that chooses its underneath data structure in runtime. For example, `unordered_set` could change from the hash table with chaining to the hash table with open addressing depending on data.

Comment: @DAle - With iterator invalidation guarantees left intact? I don't think there's much wriggle room. But I'll be pleasantly surprised to be proven wrong.

Comment: `unordered_set` also has interfaces to iterate over buckets and extract nodes, so it's pretty much locked into being a chain based hash table.

Comment: Yep, `unordered_set` was a bad example, `set` looks more promising

Comment: @storyteller, I completely understand and agree with your point about someone coming up with a better implementation must be able to use it. My question is more about how it works today with the standard containers we have got..  I mean every time I use a std::vector or std::list, I do it with the assumption that they already have defined implementation in place. So in the current C++ stl, don't the implementation of these use some fixed data structures or to be specific, don't these have a concrete implementation in place?

Comment: @abhi - The specification in place today probably has only one general way in which it can be implemented. But unless you have ABI compatibility issues to consider, why should you care how it's implemented (beyond an academic interest)? You get a complexity and API guarantee. That's enough to write some very good code.